# Flutter Heap Space issue - Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 8589934608 bytes

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I have a Flutter application using Flutter version 2.0.4.
The application is set up for Android and iOS.
The application is running fine since a self-defined search function is called which is communicating with Google Firestore.
When I start searching, the following error occurs and the app stops responding.

[VERBOSE-2:profiler_metrics_ios.mm(203)] Error retrieving thread information: (os/kern) invalid argument
Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 8589934608 bytes.
Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 8589934608 bytes.
Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 8589934608 bytes.
...

At first I thought that the Firestore communication is corrupt or provides too much data, but this can be ruled out since the search requires a previous query of the database, which succeeds every time.
Additionally, the sign-in functionality works with the Google Cloud Platform and succeed every time.

I already tried to checkout the complete project from github again, run "flutter clean" several times and reinstall Intellij and the Flutter SDK. I don't know what else I can do to avoid this problem.

Thanks for your help!!!

Best regards,
Simon

Comment: With so little information in the question itself, this isn't really a good fit for Stack Overflow. We'd need to have at least a broad idea of what your application is doing and how it's configured, and/or see some debugging information to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear in the first place. But what additional information are required?  I like to provide everything I can, but because there are no additional loggings etc. I'm not sure what information can help. - Thank you for your help

Comment: You mean there is no code of your own? Then it should be easy to provide a [mre]. Otherwise, try to pare down the code you are asking about to make it short enough to include in the question along with repro steps.

Comment: My self defined code can be described as an iterative query on the firestore by checking for equal conditions among Strings. Actually all of the code explained have worked fine since this yesterday. Everything was performing good without generating to much traffic. 
Therefore, I assume that this issue is somehow to the Flutter SDK itself.

Comment: Based on your error the linked Q&A should help or even solve the issue but please keep in mind the issue may also have to do with your code and without seeing it, and what troubleshooting you've done, there's no way for us to help.